# Access email pseudo class of input element from React?

Tags: reactjs, validation, input

I have an email input element in my react component. I use the default email validation rules for input and the `:invalid` pseudo class is set to the input element when the value is invalid (as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email).

I'd like to access whether the input element is invalid or not within my React component.

I guess I am looking for how to determine `const valuesIsInvalid` in the code below.

How can I find this value?

```
render() {
    const valueIsInvalid = ???

    return (
        <input 
            type="email" 
            value={this.state.value}
            ...
        />
        {this.props.showInvalidValueError && valueIsInvalid (
            <Text color="red">{t.emailInput.error}</Text>
        )}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the validity of an HTML element using the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript).

You can either access this value from `onChange` function with `event.target` or directly access it by setting a `ref`. The below sample demonstrates the former.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputEmail: "",
    emailValid: true,
  };
  changeEmail = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const validity = event.target.validity;
    this.setState({
      inputEmail: value,
      emailValid: validity.valid,
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { emailValid } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <input
          type="email"
          state={this.state.inputEmail}
          onChange={this.changeEmail}
          required
        />
        { !emailValid && (
          <p>Input is not valid</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access the `value` of your `input` field in outside the `render` method. 
For this, you can use [React Refs API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

You can write the following code:-

```
render() {
// now you have access to your email input field and can do any type
// of changes to this input
const valuesIsInvalid = this.emailInput 

return (
    <input 
        type="email" 
        value={this.state.value}
        ref={(input) => this.emailInput = input}
        ...
    />
    {this.props.showInvalidValueError && valueIsInvalid (
        <Text color="red">{t.emailInput.error}</Text>
    )}
)
}
```

I am using the old one [callback ref api](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Comment: I don't understand how to determine valuesIsInvalid from your example. You write const valuesIsInvalid = this.emailInput which to me seems to not make sense.

Comment: @user1283776, I mean to say that this ref api will give you complete access to your input field so you can do whatever you want.